# Can I stop Carthage from building for iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, dylib, carthage

I have a framework that uses a `dylib` file that is only compiled for `armv7`, `armv7s` and `arm64`. When I build it in Xcode, it compiles fine in both Debug and Release configurations. But when I try to get it to compile into the main app using Carthage, Carthage tries to build it twice - once using `SDKROOT = iphoneos10.3` and again using `SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.3`. This is even when I use the `--platform ios` flag. When it compiles for `iphonesimulator10.3` it crashes, obviously.

Is there a way I can stop Carthage from building for the simulator?